14 Part 121 Subpart U
14 Part 25 Subpart U states that it covers "Dispatching and Flight Release Rules". I am trying to understand why the FAA made a clear difference in using the words "dispatching" for Domestic and Flag rules versus "Flight Release" rules for Supplemental. It doesn't appear the FAA has loaded historical NPRMs for Part 121 on www.drs.gov so I can't read the FAA's reasoning or comments on why they wrote the subpart and rules (e.g., 121.591) this way years ago.
Why didn't the FAA just use "Dispatch" for all three operations?
